# How to set header value in asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I want to be able to set header value/secret key in asp.net web api, so that anybody can not just use the web service except he or she has the secret key, and also, if i could set this on the api side, how do user retrieves this value/secret key on client side and use it while consuming the service.

i have tried this, but not sure whether i am right. below is my code:

```
public IQueryable<PaymentApi> GetPaymentApi()
   {
       var re = Request;
       var headers = re.Headers;
       if(headers.Contains("rtyuiopjhfghjuiopJKLKLJH"))
       {
           return db.PaymentApi;
       }
       return null;
   }
```

Thanks for your response.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? StackOverflow is meant for isolated specific problems that can be recreated and that have a clear goal, as well as an example that somehow fails to meet that goal. Please specify exactly what you want to do and how you are failing to do that with this code.

Comment: You're thinking about [bearer tokens](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/).

Comment: if the above code is correct, how do i consume the above api and provide the needed key?